# Run git command from Databricks Notebook

Tags: git, databricks

It is now possible to link your git repository in Databricks. However, it looks like you can only commit&push or pull using the interface by clicking on the buttons.

Is there anyway to run some code in the notebook directly to commit, push or pull.

I tried to do the following but I get an error:

```
%sh git pull
```

error: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

The main reason I want to do this is to run a job on a weekly basis and make sure I pull the last changes sitting on develop before running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that because notebooks aren't the real files on the disk - these objects are stored not on the file system.  Yes, they could be linked to Git, but they aren't files inside the Databricks.

Right now, there is a private preview of the feature called "[Projects](https://docs.databricks.com/projects.html)" that will allow to build something like this using the [special API](https://docs.databricks.com/projects.html#projects-api-experimental).  You can ask your admins to contact Databricks about this feature, because it's quite handy, and easier integrated with CI/CD systems, etc. - for example, you can look to [this demo](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo).

In the meantime you can implement as following:

1. Link your notebooks to the Git - this will be the development copy, that you're working on, using UI push/commit/pull
2. Create a separate folder to keep notebooks for a job
3. Setup CI/CD pipeline that will listen for commits, fetch the changed notebooks, and copy them to the separate folder using the `import` or `import_dir` commands of the [Databricks Workspace CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html).  More detailed steps could be found on [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/implement-ci-cd-azure-devops/) (if you're using Azure), but the steps are similar for other CI/CD systems.